# Guidance for a vb.net programmer moving to metro

Tags: microsoft-metro

I know vb.net pretty well (and I've done a little WPF) but want to take a look at Windows 8 / Metro style programming with VS Express for Windows 8.

Are there any good articles to help with this?

I started a blank project and bits of it look familiar, but I wanted to try drawing a number of circles on the page to test the graphics speed. I'd have done that in the form OnRender event in vb, but although I have a similarish looking list of events, there isn't anything like OnRender or OnPaint.

How do I just draw a shape (circle) on the page (in vb code)? Can't seem to find very much on google for metro / windows 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete package of samples for Windows 8 development, including VB code. It's a definitely good place to start.
[Windows 8 app samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples)
Or you can use this link:
[Create your first Windows Store app using C# or Visual Basic (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx)